# Left outer join with CASE condition on most recent date

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

```
dbo.Order

PK_Order    FK_Customer OrderDate   Total
1           1           2020-01-20  150.00
2           1           2020-01-25  200.00

dbo.Customer:

PK_Customer Name            Age
1           John Miller     25
2           Max Monroe      28
```

I would like to join these two tables BUT when a customer has more than one order, only the one with the most recent date should be joined. This would be the initial code to join the two:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Customer as Customer
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Order 
ON Customer.PK_Customer = dbo.Order.FK_Customer
```

I have never worked with case conditions in queries. Could anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

I like using `TOP 1 WITH TIES` for problems like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM dbo.Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN o
    ON c.PK_Customer = o.FK_Customer
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.PK_Customer ORDER BY o.OrderDate DESC);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can LEFT JOIN only record with the latest date:

```
--CREATE TABLE [Order]
--(
--  PK_Order int,
--  FK_Customer int,
--  OrderDate date,
--  Total decimal(10,2)
--)
--INSERT [Order] VALUES
--(1,1,'2020-01-20',150),
--(2,1,'2020-01-25',200)

--CREATE TABLE Customer
--(
--  PK_Customer int,
--  Name nvarchar(20),
--  Age int
--)
--INSERT [Customer] VALUES
--(1,'John Miller',25),
--(2,'Max Monroe',28)

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.Customer C
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Order] O
  ON C.PK_Customer = O.FK_Customer
 AND OrderDate=(SELECT MAX(OrderDate) FROM [Order] WHERE [Order].FK_Customer=O.FK_Customer)
```

Note 1: Since there can be many orders in recent date, I preserve all.

Note 2: It's not a good idea to keep age - it must be updated every year. Keep date of birth.

Answer (score 0):

A similar way to Tim's answer but the difference is that the Partition by is within orders table and joining on Row =1 for each customer.

```
select * from #Customer c 
left join 
(select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by FK_Customer order by OrderDate desc) as order_NUM,
        PK_Order,
        FK_Customer,
        OrderDate,
        Total from #Order
    ) o on c.PK_Customer = o.FK_Customer and order_NUM = 1
     order by c.PK_Customer, o.OrderDate desc
```